# Database of services and related information for various Linux distributions

Tags: linux, database, service

I am looking for a database/list of common services and related information dovering various linux distributions. For instance for `MySQL`, the list would indicate that the init script is at `/etc/init.d/mysqld` on `RHEL` and `/etc/init.d/mysql` on Ubuntu. The same logic would be followed for other distributions and other information such as the paths to configuration files or log directories...

**Do you know where I can find such a list/database?**

Comment: Knowing that we have to type `mysqld` instead of `mysql` is why we get paid the big bucks!

Comment: Well, medium-large bucks, anyway!  user64204, you have an **awful** lot of questions without accepted answers; you might want to spend a few minutes going back and seeing if you can improve your "accepted answer" ratio.

Comment: @MadHatter: I don't know why though, as far as I can see I only have 6 out of 60 which I haven't accepted which should make my ratio at 90%. I have many questions without any answers though, maybe those are taken into account too, which they shouldn't IMO, having a separate percentage such as `Interest rate` to show how many of your questions didn't get a single answer would be more appropriate I believe.

Comment: user64204, I just did a quick count and came up with 23 questions you've asked with no accepted answer and a non-zero number of answers.  Surely some of them have a decent answer?  I agree with you about not including questions without answers; you might want to pop onto meta and make that argument.

Comment: @MadHatter: I believe you, but when I go to my profile and then the `questions` tab, I only have `2` pages of questions in which I only see `6` not accepted answers (i.e. with the `Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?` warning on top of them): where do you see those `23` not accepted answers?. FYI in addition I have `6` questions with no answers at all, so even by adding those 2 categories (not accepted and not answered) I only get to `6+6=12`. Weird.

Comment: In your questions page, anything where the answer count is non-zero and in a light-coloured bounding box means no answer has been accepted.  The following questions are the first (after this one) that don't have an accepted answer: How to investigate peak in MySQL throughput?, Changing MySQL startup timeout ([fail] reported although mysql properly started), Which section of the MySQL configuration can a variable be placed under?, Short write and read speed disk benchmarking, HUDSON: how to manually encode the LDAP managerPassword? - and that just takes me halfway down the first of two pages.

Comment: Right, I'd never paid attention to the light green boxes, was always relying on the aforementioned warning. Did some acceptance. 82% looks better indeed. I guess all these folks that provided answers months ago are gonna be happy now :)

Comment: Indeed - well done that user!

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is http://rpmfind.net , however, it only covers RPM, although it does this for several distributions.

Basically however, each package management system, either RPM or DEB, will show the path for currently installed package files, including config file location.

Fpr example, to see where mysql has config files on Ubuntu system, you could do something like:

```
dpkg -l 'mysql*' | grep ii
```

(grep ii shows only installed packages), and then:

```
dpkg -L mysql-common
```

will then show the my.cnf file is located in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

For RPM systems there are similar options, if I recall correctly there was option for RPM to specifically show only config file locations.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  Here's Ubuntu's wiki page on switching from RHEL to them, which has some of the equivalent package management commands:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora

You can run `dpkg -L packagename` and `rpm -ql packagename` to get the package contents, which will give you a good clue as to what the startup service commands are.  The main differences you'll encounter will lie in package management and service startup customs, as you'll see in that Ubuntu page.